# Is there a way to move the Repository folder of Visual SVN Server?

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server

Can I move the Repository folder after the installation of Visual SVN Server? I need to move my repositories in a folder in which the user "NETWORK SERVICE" cannot write.

Comment: Here can be different installations of 'SVN Server'. Which one you mean?

Comment: I have installed VisualSVN Server 3.3.1 for Windows. My goal is to move a repository folder in a directory in which only a particular user can access to. I would move the repository folder only after to have modified the user on "Log on as" in all the services of SVN instead of "NETWORK SERVICE" user.

Comment: May be you can add deny permissions for NETWORK SERVICE for existing folder?

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly your answer. Why Can I should add deny permissions fro NETWORK SERVICE? Anyway I cannot modify the permissions for the folder in which I would like to move my SVN repositories. My problem is that during the installation of VisualSVN Server 3.3.1, when you have to set the path of the repositories folder, I couldn't set the wanted path of my folder because in this folder the NETWORK SERVICE user couldn't write. So I set another path to go on. Now, after I have changed the user related to SVN all services, I want to move the repositories folder in my wanted f..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK. Seems I understand question now.

1. Stop VisualSVN Server,
2. Copy repositories (if any exist, e.g. `C:\Repositories`) to desired destination,
3. Start VisualSVN Server Manager console and go to **Action | Properties | Storage**,
4. Update repositories location path to the new parent of all repositories (the directory where you moved you repositories),
5. Click Apply and close the dialog,
6. Make sure that you've [configured NTFS permissions for VisualSVN Server's service account](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00037/). If you have to use non-default account to run the service (i.e. not `Network Service`) then [read this doc](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00024/).
7. Start VisualSVN Server.

Comment: What about other services, such as VisualSVN Background Job Service, VisualSVN Distributed File System Service & VisaulSVN Repository Configurator Service?

Comment: I do not know about these services. May be them was introduced after I wrote this post.